# La strada per l’inferno

Tags: phrase-origin, proverbs

...***è lastricata di buone intenzioni.***

Riflettendo sul significato di questo detto comune, mi chiedo se il senso sia “religioso” cioè  che sia  così difficile compiere buone azioni che inevitabilmente si erra e si finisce “condannati”, oppure se il senso sia più “laico” cioè  che le “buone intenzioni” siano in realtà una serie di comportamenti mirati al divertimento e alla leggerezza il cui risultato finale sia inevitabilmente qualcosa di negativo.

[Ci sono varie citazioni di questo detto in rete](https://www.google.com/search?q=la%20strada%20per%20l%20inferno%20%C3%A8%20lastricata%20di%20buone%20intenzioni&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=la%20strada%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i60l2.3814j0j7&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) ma non ho trovato una spiegazione chiara, nemmeno riguardo alla sua origine spesso attribuita a Karl Marx, ma c’è chi obbietta e sostiene che:

> Ma Marx non ha il merito di essere l'originatore di questo detto. Lo ha copiato da altri, tra cui uno dei primi a farne un proverbio di questa idea risale al 1670 col nome di John Ray che disse, "Hell is paved with good intentions."

Qualcuno ha informazioni più precise in merito al significato e all’origine del detto?

Comment: Personalmente (e quindi non è una risposta), l'ho sempre inteso nel senso che avendo solo buoni propositi, ma non traducendoli in azioni concrete, non si ottiene niente o addirittura si fa una brutta fine.

Comment: Si tratta della traduzione all'italiano di [questo proverbio inglese](https://grammarist.com/proverb/the-road-to-hell-is-paved-with-good-intentions/)?

Comment: Perché il -1? Cosa non va nella mia domanda?

Comment: Qual è la fonte della tua citazione? (Non sono stato io a dare il -1, a scanso di equivoci.)

Comment: Hai visto la [pagina di Wikipedia inglese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions) del detto? Mi sembra che dia delle buone risposte alle tue domande.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Però quella pagina parla appunto di un detto inglese, mentre qui parliamo di uno analogo italiano, che quella pagina non menziona.